# libgnutls version and protocol standard correspondence

Tags: ssl, gnutls

I need to find out if `gnutls` library that I have installed supports `TLS 1.2` or `TLS 1.3`. I kept looking online but there doesn't seem to be a correspondence between library version and protocol standard. So to provide more clarification, here is what I see

```
$ ls -lah /usr/lib/libgnutls.so
/usr/lib/libgnutls.so -> ibgnutls.so.30.22.0
```

From this I can see that my library is at version `30.22.0` (we can talk more about library versioning later if you want). What I can't figure out is what protocol version does this library support. Is it `TLS 1.2` or `TLS 1.3` or both? To find out what `TLS` source code version I have installed I downloaded a dev version of `gnutls` and looked into `/usr/include/gnutls/gnutls.h`. Found the following in there

```
#define GNUTLS_VERSION "3.6.4"

#define GNUTLS_VERSION_MAJOR 3
#define GNUTLS_VERSION_MINOR 6
#define GNUTLS_VERSION_PATCH 4

#define GNUTLS_VERSION_NUMBER 0x030604
```

So it looks like I'm using version 3.6.4 of the source code. I also kept digging online, but couldn't determine if this version support `TLS 1.2`, `TLS 1.3` or both.

Any help with this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://gnutls.org/news.html:

> 2018-09-24
>   Released GnuTLS 3.6.4 of the next branch with support for the final version of TLS1.3.

Thus, the version you have (3.6.4) should support TLS 1.3.

Comment: Do you know what does "GnuTLS 3.6.4 of the next branch" mean?

Comment: @flashburn: likely the branch where the "future" development is vs. the "stable" branch where mainly bug fixes happen.

Comment: If TLS 3.6.4 supports TLS 1.3, does it mean it supports 1.2 as well? I can't figure this out from the source code or documentation.

Comment: @flashburn: Of course it does. Every modern TLS library does support  TLS 1.0 ... TLS 1.2. Otherwise they would not be able to communicate with the majority of TLS endpoints.

Comment: My team is moving to TLS 1.2 because TLS 1.1 has some sort of a security bug. I'm trying to understand what are the implications if two machines are communicating and one of them is using TLS 1.1 and another is using TLS 1.2. Will my TLS 1.2 machine be at any risk if it is communicating with TLS 1.1 machine?

Comment: @flashburn: This is a different question and should not be asked in a comment. But in short: if the best the server can do is TLS 1.1 the TLS connection will be done with TLS 1.1 unless the client explicitly refuses to do it. If the client can only do TLS 1.2 or better and the server only TLS 1.1 or worse the connection will fail. Also, there is no issue with TLS 1.1 which affects the client machines. Protocol issues (instead of implementation issues) at most risk that an attacker can get access to the communication but they don't affect the actual machines involved.